# Group Policy no longer applying desktop wallpaper

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, desktop-customization

I used to have my wallpapers updated monthly by Group Policy. 
Several months ago I was prompted (I think just after logon) to grant GPO (I think) access to a wallpaper setting in the registry. It was the first (and last) time I had seen this prompt and it seems whatever response I selected stopped GPO from being able to update my desktop wallpaper. 
Unfortunately, I cannot remember what the setting was nor what the prompt was.

What I would like to do is re-allow GPO to update my wallpaper.

I have local admin. I'm running Windows 7.

Thanks.